# Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).Message(name) does not call to the client JavaScript method in SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, signalr

I am using `SignalR` to update the user tasks in Asp.net MVC.
But I have the problem, in my hub `SignalR` class, the below method does not call client side method to update the task with client `connectionId`.
I am getting `connectionId` from connections List when user login to the system.
The thing is that user has successfully logout by using `connectionId`, but this is problem in this case to update his tasks?
Where is the problem?

**strong SignalR Hub Method text**

```
public void InvitationForConference(long assignedTo)
{
    try
    {
        var connectionId = GetUserCoonectionId(assignedTo);

        // Update Tasks
        Clients.Client(connectionId).invitationForAllConference(assignedTo);

        // Update Notifications
        Clients.Client(connectionId).invitationNotificationForAllConference(assignedTo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**strong Js Client Method text**

```
signalR.client.invitationForAllConference = function (AssignedId) 
{
    debugger
    LoadTasks(AssignedId);
};

**strong  Js File text**
var IsLogin = '';
IsLogin = $("#LoginConnectionId").val();
var signalR = $.connection.signalRHUB;
debugger;
if (IsLogin == "OPEN") {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        debugger
        IsLogin == "CLOSE";
        signalR.server.createConnection();
    });
}
else {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {  });
}
signalR.client.invitationForAllConference = function (AssignedId) {
    debugger
    LoadTasks(AssignedId);
};
signalR.client.invitationNotificationForAllConference = function (AssignedId) {
    debugger
    LoadNotificationAlerts(AssignedId);
};

[Authorize]
public class SignalRHUB : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =
       new ConnectionMapping<string>();
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser, long> _userManager;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWorkLazyLoad;

    public SignalRHUB(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUnitOfWork unitOfWorkLazyLoad)
    {
        try
        {
            //_userManager = userManager;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _unitOfWorkLazyLoad = unitOfWorkLazyLoad;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }


    public void InvitationForConference(long assignedTo)
    {
        try
        {
            var connectionId = GetUserCoonectionId(assignedTo);

            // Update Tasks
            Clients.Client(connectionId).invitationForAllConference(assignedTo);

            // Update Notifications
            Clients.Client(connectionId).invitationNotificationForAllConference(assignedTo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show whole JS file, where we see how you start the connection....

Comment: var IsLogin = '';
IsLogin = $("#LoginConnectionId").val();
var signalR = $.connection.signalRHUB;
debugger;
if (IsLogin == "OPEN") {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        debugger
        IsLogin == "CLOSE";
        signalR.server.createConnection();

    });
}
else {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {  });
}
signalR.client.invitationForAllConference = function (AssignedId) {
    debugger
    LoadTasks(AssignedId);
};  This is my js file

Comment: Please modify your question with that code. It not really readable in this comment

Comment: Yes sir,I have do it on my above question box

Comment: by the whay did you any error in console output? Your JS looks a bit strange.....

Comment: Ok sorry then it's not clear whats not running.Han you also post code whole hub? Is there any authorization attribute?

Comment: Yes on hub [authorize] attribute is  used

Comment: I have attached my hub class on my question box,You can see it

Comment: do you have also the same if you remove authorize attribbut (only for test)

Comment: I remove authorize attribute,but nothing is diiferent,i found the same result.

Answer (score 1):

**You must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the start method**

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client:

> Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method
>   to establish the connection. If you want to register some event
>   handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you
>   must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the
>   start method. One reason for this is that there can be many Hubs in an
>   application, but you wouldn't want to trigger the OnConnected event on
>   every Hub if you are only going to use to one of them. When the
>   connection is established, the presence of a client method on a Hub's
>   proxy is what tells SignalR to trigger the OnConnected event. If you
>   don't register any event handlers before calling the start method, you
>   will be able to invoke methods on the Hub, but the Hub's OnConnected
>   method won't be called and no client methods will be invoked from the
>   server.

Comment: Thanku sir, But when i call Clients.All.invitationForAllConference() ,  then this call goes at client side,but i want to send to only specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of trying things, have you tried using connectionID passed by hub context? `this.Context.ConnectionId`this is the current id of the clients call, compare the ID you pull to that and see if its correct.

Other issue that i had with client methods not being called is that the proxy hubs have not been initialized properly before connection started, so i would look into that aswell. Hope it helps.